# How to create custom exception message for on_delete=models.PROTECT in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two classes in models file `Add_cat` and `Add_prod`.Through the first class I created category and through second class I created book name,author,price and image.I made category as a foreign key in my 2nd class and then I created some records for add_prod.Through templates I created a button for deleting the selected category.If the selected category contains records we cant delete it because I used ondelete=models.PROTECT,now if I try to delete a category which contains records in the add_prod table django gives me an exception like this,`("Cannot delete some instances of model 'Add_cat' because they are referenced through a protected foreign key: 'Add_prod.cat'", [<Add_prod: Add_prod object>])`.Is it possible to create a custom exception message instead of displaying the default exception?

Models.py,

```
class Add_cat(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField("Name",max_length=25,unique=True,error_messages={'unique':"This category already exists"})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.category)

class Add_prod(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField("Book Name",max_length=40)
    author = models.CharField("Author",max_length=30)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField("Price")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Add_cat,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Views.py,

```
def del_cat(request,pk):
    query = Add_cat.objects.get(pk=pk)
    query.delete()
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Category Deleted')
    return redirect("add_cat")
```

Delete button in my template file,

```
<button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete?');"><a href="{% url 'del_prod' pk=i.pk %}">Delete</a></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple matter of sorrounding with try except

```
def del_cat(request,pk):
    try:
        query = Add_cat.objects.get(pk=pk)
        query.delete()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Category Deleted')
        return redirect("add_cat")
    except:
       return HttpResponse('Cant delete that row mate')
```

Instead of sending out a simple error like this, you would probably want to render some template or add a message as you do for successfull events but this time to indicate that the category couldn't be deleted and then redirect.

```
  messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Category Not Deleted')
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help